# Copy a single file and rename based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder that contains a master file, I like to copy it to a different folder and create new file names based on excel cell value.

Master file --Different folder location ---create files based on cell value(john.pdf, mike.pdf and smith.pdf)

The code I have below, but this only copies one cell value and i have a list to create and rename.

```
Sub CollectArt()
Dim FSO As Object
Dim SourceFileName, DestinFileFolder As String
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Sheets("input").Range("Y2:Y100")

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
SourceFileName = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\template\master.pdf"
For Each cell In rng
If Len(cell) > 0 Then
FSO.CopyFile Source:=SourceFileName, Destination:=DestinFileFolder

DestinFileFolder = cell.Value

Exit For
End If
Next cell


End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: Yes, but I just don't know how to loop through every cell value.

Comment: You have `exit for` The loop only runs once then exits